# Node.js, cluster, express, apache ab and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, performance-testing

I'm new to mongo and have a few performance tests setup with Node.js (v0.4.12), cluster (Learnboost v0.7.7) and express (v2.5.9).  I'm trying to connect to mongo and do a simple performance test with apache ab.  I've set this up with MySql and it works flawlessly, but when I try to do the same test with mongo I don't get the results I expect.

With MySql, I send 10,000 requests to the node.js cluster (8 cores) and I get 10,000 rows inserted into the db.  No issues.  But, when I do the same thing with mongo, I only get around 4,500-4,900.  I've tried mongoskin, mongo-lite, node-mongodb-native and all have exactly the same result.

I thought maybe it was the pool size, so I increased/decreased that.  Nothing.  No errors or exceptions.  I'm at a loss...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

The code for the test is below;

### app.js

```
var mongoLite = require('mongo-lite');
var express   = require('express');

var count  = 1;
var config = {
host    : 'localhost', 
user    : USER,
pass    : PASSWORD,
port    : '27017',
db      : 'test',
options : 'poolSize=10'
};

var configUrl = 'mongodb://'    +
              config.user + ':' + 
              config.pass + '@' + 
              config.host + ':' + 
              config.port + '/' +
              config.db;


var mongo   = mongoLite.connect(configUrl);
var server  = express.createServer();

server.get('/test/:id', function (req, res) {               
mongo.collection('test_' + req.params.id).insert({_id: count++}, function(err, doc){
    if (err)
        throw err;
});
res.end('inserted');
});

module.exports = server;
```

### server.js

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

cluster('./app')
    .use(cluster.reload())
    .use(cluster.logger('logs'))
    .use(cluster.stats())
    .use(cluster.pidfiles('pids'))
    .use(cluster.cli())
    .use(cluster.repl(8888))
    .listen(81);
```

Comment: You should try this with safe inserts. Change the insert line to 

`mongo.collection('test_' + req.params.id).insert({_id: count++}, {safe:true}, function(err, doc){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I've had these issues with apache ab. My conclusion was that it was firing requests at node faster than it could handle them, and because if this certain requests just weren't getting handled at all.

I wrote my own benchmark test to do http connections in Java as a workaround

Comment: That is good to know!  But, I wonder why it works fine with MySQL and not mongo?

Comment: My guess would be that the problem has to do with Mongo's speed. Either requests are getting rejected outright it is breaking because of too many connections